# Memory leak in long running windows service with non stopping Socket Listener

Tags: sockets, memory-leaks, tcp, windows-services

I wrote a TCP async listener using sockets. It will listen from only one client which sends ~8 messages per second for 24/7. I hosted that in a windows service, to make it alive for all day long. It works well for some time and all of sudden the memory consumption is getting increasing like anything. This is making my listener to hang and not listening the incoming data. But still windows service is showing as running. I think my program is busy in listening which is not letting the GC to clear the memory, is it correct? or Is this common for long running TCP Listener windows service.

Please suggest. I am stuck here.

Comment: What have you done so far to debug the problem yourself?  Without seeing your code and troubleshooting efforts, your question is off-topic as-is. There is no useful info for us to diagnose with.

Comment: please add language information as well as some code. one could only guess what might be the problem but this is not a quiz site :-)